# python or bash script that does something when there is no response(output)

Tags: python, bash

There is an external program A.
I want to write a script that does some action if the called external program A does not bring up any output(stout).

How is this possible in bash or python?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) Do you konw [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) [questions the smart way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the subprocess module which allows you to execute system calls and store its output in variables which can be used later on.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess as sub

ur_call = '<your system call here>'

p = sub.Popen(ur_call, stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.PIPE)
output, errors = p.communicate()
if len(output) == 0 and len(errors) == 0:       
    pass  # Do something
```

Answer (score 0):

In a Bash-script, you could redirect the output to a file, and if the length of the file is zero then there was no output.

Answer (score 0):

If the script that sometimes gives output is no.sh then you can do this in Python:

```
import os                                                                                                                                              
x = os.popen("./no.sh")
y = x.read()
if y:
    print "Got output"
```

Comment: Python doc says:

os.popen(command[, mode[, bufsize]])

Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the subprocess module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section.

http://docs.python.org/library/os.html